# Building C# String That Includes JavaScript Code

Tags: c#, javascript, string

I have this very simple C# function that builds a string that will be written to a html document - the string includes javascript code that will be executed by the browser once the final page is built is sent on its way. I am getting errors - New Line in Constant. I have done this type of thing 1000s of times. I have NOT tried using a StringBuilder class - string should work just as well. I tried escaping the single quotes into quotes (replaced all ' with /") - no luck. What am I missing?

Here is the function:

```
public string TranslateButtons()
{
    string html = "";

    html += "<div style='float:right;'>";
    html += "<div id='translate-this'><a style='width:180px; height:18px; display:block;' class='translate-this-button' href='http://www.translatecompany.com/'>Translate Company</a></div>";
    html += "<script type='text/javascript' src='http://x.translateth.is/translate-this.js'></script>";
    html += "<script type='text/javascript'>";
    html += "TranslateThis();";
    html += "</script>";
    html += "</div>";

    return html;
}
```

The offending lines are the ones that include `<script>` or `</script>` - I even tried removing lines 1 by 1 - if I include any line with script tags I get the error.

Running: IIS 8.0 - Windows 8 - .NET Framework 4.0

Comment: could you be more specific, what is the error ?

Comment: I just created a webpage in Visual Studio and copy-pasted your function.  It appears to work fine.  You may be getting the error from somewhere else on the page?

Comment: @Selman22 he did specify the error 'New Line in constant'

Comment: Maybe one or more of your single quotes is the wrong type?  Sounds weird, but I've seen it happen!   Try copying the function into a text editor, then copy it back... or try manually deleting quotes and re entering them in the ide.

Comment: Have you tried prefixing the strings with the `@` symbol?

Comment: The problem is definitely in the function and not somewhere else - I add it to the end of a class that is tried and proven. I can also just leave the function and remove the offending lines. Interesting note - If I only comment out the offending line I still get errors, but the error changes to:

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS1513: } expected. This error almost appears to be a compiler bug - it does not like some sequence of characters in the offending lines. Like I said I've done this type of thing 1000s before and this is one strange bug.

Comment: But on the other hand MrVimes cut and paste the code and had no problems. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Developer and .NET Framework 4.5 (I listed 4.0 earlier)

Comment: I tried prefix the strings with @ and the error stayed the same: Compiler Error Message: CS1010: Newline in constant. One last note - I moved the function to the top of the class - to see if there was any strange problem with nesting of } etc. - no change - the problem is in the script lines. I put the offending javascript lines into the html and just kept the <div> lines and everything works. If would be interesting to find out why these 3 or 4 lines won't compile.

Comment: I still think it's your double quotes.  Try copying the text from your question above.

Also please provide a screenshot.  I am curious to find out what is causing this.  Do you not have squiggly lines pointing out where the error is?  Hover over them with your mouse to see the error.

Comment: 'Constant' refers to the string. 'Newline' refers to the fact that there is a line break before the string is 'closed' (with the final double quote)  This is why I think it is your double quotes.  I can't see anything else in the string line generating this specific error.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  Care to reveal what the problem was?  If not, have you tried the other suggestions?

Comment: MrVimes, I was able to solve it by removing the script lines and putting them into the html doc - this was far from ideal. I wanted the code to only be included in certain cases, Now it is always there - extra JavaScript, especially from external sources is never a good thing. I checked and re-checked the physical characters in the strings and they are fine. It makes no sense.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the time get held up on these small things - I will revisit this in the future. If you want to see it on a live site: http://giirugs.com/blog/?aid=31 - it's used on all the individual articles. I have a custom translation solution that will replace the generic translate button - we are only interested in Spanish (for now).

Comment: btw: I am the sole developer of above mentioned site.

Answer (score 4):

I did some experimentation.

If I replace one of the double quotes in your code with a 'Double Acute Accent' I get the new line in constant error.

[image]

So you need to make sure all your double quotes are the standard type rather than the 'Double Acute Accent' or 'Double Grave Accent'

They creep in when you copy-paste code from certain places such as rich text editors or websites.

Try deleting your double quotes and re-entering them in your IDE.

**Or**,  try copying the code from your stackoverflow question (as I did) and paste it over 'itself' in your IDE.  This may replace the weird double quotes with normal ones.

Comment: I tried that 1st thing - I used notepad to sure there were no strange characters

Comment: Try copying the code from your question above and replacing your function with the copied one. Maybe notepad is retaining the unusual double quotes.

Comment: Also,  could you maybe take a screenshot showing the error and the code?   Maybe that will help us identify the cause.   Your code as it is in the question seems to be fine.